# How can i download only latest file by Get-AzureStorageBlobContent

Tags: powershell, azure

I Have written this code. How can i download only latest file?

```
$container_name = 'packageitems'
$destination_path = 'C:\pstest'
$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTNAME];AccountKey=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTKEY]'

$storage_account = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connection_string

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $storage_account

foreach ($blob in $blobs)
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path

    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path `
    -Context $storage_account

}
```

Comment: What does the code have to do with the question? Have you tried anything? Did you try checking the properties of each blob for example?

Comment: This code download all the files from the container, I want to download only latest file

Comment: It's still not related to the question. Have you tried something? Even goolging for `Powershell find newest file` will give you a hint

Comment: How many files are there in your blob container? How do you define the latest file?

Comment: On the bases of Last Modified

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
$container_name = 'packageitems'
$destination_path = 'C:\pstest'
$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTNAME];AccountKey=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTKEY]'
$storage_account = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connection_string
# Get the blobs list and then sort them by last modified date descending
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $storage_account  | sort @{expression="LastModified";Descending=$true}
# First blob in that list would be the last modified.
$latestBlob = $blobs[0]
# Just download that blob
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $container_name -Blob $latestBlob.Name -Destination $destination_path `
    -Context $storage_account
```

What the code above does is lists the blobs and then sorts them in descending order based on the last modified date. The 1st element in the array will be the latest blob. It then downloads this blob.